# One main effect and one interaction in R using multiple regression, is that possible? And why am I getting two interaction terms in output?

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I have two factors that are fully crossed, the levels of the factor are each coded 0 and 1. I am running a regression testing for one main effect and one interaction. The following is my logistic regression formula:

```
m1=glmer(y~1+A+A:B+(1|Participants)+(1|Word),data=data, family = "binomial")
```

I am wondering if this is acceptable (only testing for one main effect and an interaction), and also why I am getting two interaction terms in my output:

```
Fixed effects:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept) -0.18740    0.21600  -0.868  0.38561   
A1           0.74546    0.28399   2.625  0.00867 **
A0:B1        0.01537    0.28244   0.054  0.95662   
A1:B1        0.15884    0.28650   0.554  0.57929
```

Comment: Please migrate it to CV.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are not including the main effect of B in your model? It's generally best to include main effects of variables for which you are examining interactions.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 possible states for the interaction of `A` and `B`. That is

1. `A0:B0`, and not shown as it is absorbed into the intercept term for the regression.
2. `A1` (implicitly `A1:B0`).
3. `A0:B1`.
4. `A1:B1`.

Each of these states affects the response in a different way.